# Equivalence for sequentially compact space for Hausdorff spaces.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Show that $X$ is sequentially compact if and only if for every closed set $A$ of $X$ and every continuous function $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ has a maximum. I think this should follow from Urysohn's lemma but I don't really see how to approach this problem. I know that since $X$ is Hausdorff, we also get that $X$ is normal. So in particular, $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, however I don't know if this would get me anywhere...

Comment: It is not necessarily true that a sequentially compact Hausdorff space is compact.

Answer (score 1):

This is false: $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ is compact Hausdorff (so every real-valued continuous function assumes a max) but not sequentially compact. $\beta \Bbb N$ (the [Čech–Stone compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of $\Bbb N$ is another such example.

In first countable Hausdorff spaces the equivalence (pseudocompactness and sequential compactness) does hold.